# Prepare statement to insert multiple row

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am trying to insert multiple rows of data by using one prepare statement but it unable to insert data into database. Below is my code:

```
$count = count(array_filter($arr));
// Define a statement to insert working experience
if (!($stmt = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO work_experience_records (record_id, organization_name, location, employment_date, responsibility) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))) {
     echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
if($count > 0){

    for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
            $item = explode(' | ', $arr[$i]);
            //echo $item[0] . $item[1] .$item[2] . $item[3];
            $stmt->bind_param('issss', $next_id, $item[0], $item[1], $item[2], $item[3]);

            if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
            }
        }
    /*if(!$result = $dbc->query($query_2)){

    }*/

}
```

Did I miss something else or any wrong with my code? Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its always a good idea to print out the entire statement and then check directly in the db to see what is not working (no php dependencies). Are you getting any errors?

Comment: How should I print out the entire statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. The insert unsuccessful was due to the line

```
$result->free();
```

before the prepare and execute statements. After removing that line, the data successfully inserted.

Thanks to all replies and help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind parameters in execute method instead ([php doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO work_experience_records (record_id, organization_name, location, employment_date, responsibility) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

foreach($data as $row)
{
    $stmt->execute($row);
}
```

Comment: Is this what you mean? $stmt->execute(bind_param('issss', $next_id, $item[0], $item[1], $item[2], $item[3]));

Comment: @Therenho: I don't know about structure $arr, but I think  it should be like this:
    $stmt->execute(array($next_id, $item[0], $item[1], $item[2], $item[3]));